# How to write this return statement so I don't return null?

Tags: java, return

I don't know where or how to place my return statement so I get back a linked list. The return of the linked list is in a loop. I need to have a return statement outside that however but can't get tit to work. I just keep getting the null return. Tried putting in an else statement  but its not working. I feel like this is a simple solution but can't work it out. I know the return null is always read in this code, just don't know how to put it so it doesn't always return null.

Method is taking in a string of numbers, getting letters attached to those numbers on a keypad, and putting possible combinations of those strings into a method that finds words and returns a linked list of those words.

Just can't work out the return statement in the method.

```
 public LinkedList bfs_search(String numberEntered) {  
    //use a queue for all the unsearched combinations to go
    Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<String>();  

    q.add(""); 

    String possibleWord = null;

    //loop through each number entered
    for(int i = 0; i < numberEntered.length(); i++) {  
        //get the letters on the keypad for current number
        String lettersOnKeypadNumber = T9keypad[numberEntered.charAt(i) - ASCII_ZERO];  
        int len = q.size();  

        //loop while there are letter sequences in the queue.  Note len-- is same as len=len-1 so loop until only one item left in queue (the blank item inserted above)
        while(len -- > 0) {  
            String letterSequenceFromQ = q.remove();  
            //loop through each letter on the keypad number, add it to the letter sequence pulled from queue and search for that letter sequence as a word in the trie
            for(int j = 0; j < lettersOnKeypadNumber.length(); j++) {  
                possibleWord = letterSequenceFromQ + lettersOnKeypadNumber.charAt(j);  
                //q.add(tmpStr);  
                if(search(possibleWord) && possibleWord.length() == numberEntered.length()) {  
                    //found it!
                   return possibleWords(possibleWord); 

                } else {
                    //letter sequence is not a word, add it to the queue for possible word when get the next set of letters for the next keyed number
                    q.add(possibleWord);                      
                }  
            }  
        }

   } 
   return null;          
}
```

Comment: Return an empty linked list?

Comment: @Shark  no, the method called within this method is returning a linked list also that I am trying to return.

Comment: Yes, but you could replace your `return null` with `return new LinkedList<>()`.

Comment: @DuncanJones  Ok, you mean make a new linkelist of the linked list returned inside the method and return that?

Comment: Your return null statement is inside for loop. Move it outside for loop.

Comment: `while(len-- > 0)` looks like a bug, don't you need to re-evaluate `q.size()`?

Comment: @DuncanJones  possibly, but that part of the code is working as it is.

Comment: I'm confused, is the method returning null because `possibleWords()` returns null or because you reach your `return null;` statement? If you don't know, please use a debugger and find out.

Comment: @DuncanJones  possibleWords() is not a null return. But i can't get this to return in the bfs_search(). Always just returns the null.

Comment: the method works without a return when i just print out the variable possibleWord in the if statement, rather then pass it into the possibleWords().

Comment: Also, I can just print out the return of possibleWords() in that if statement.

Comment: "*possibleWords() is not a null return. But i can't get this to return in the bfs_search(). Always just returns the null.*" > Sorry, but this doesn't make sense to me. What "always just returns the null"?

Comment: @DuncanJones i mean that rather then the 'return possibleWords(possibleWord);'in the if statement being the return, the return is the 'return null;' that is outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method signature is a contract -- you are GOING to return a linked list.  That being the case, you need to do one of two things--return a linked list, empty or not, or throw an exception if it's really the case that there must be a linked list with > 0 items.

The q.add("") does nothing for you except make it possible to use len-- as a looping condition.  Use q.isEmpty as your control: you are either leaving the loop or adding a string to the queue.

Since you are ending the loop in your if clause, remove the else{} from around the q.add

if you really intend to return from a triple nested loop, just throw an exception and handle it in the calling function.  Otherwise, assign the value returned from possibleWords() to a local reference, and return that.

you're not making your life any easier by using one-character variables, but that's a subjective thing :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the return statement after your for loop

Comment: But calling the method possibelWords() needs to be in that if statement no?

Comment: I think he talking about the `return null;` statement

Comment: @DeadlyJesus my bad, that is where i had it, moved it out. like that it still always returns null, and not the return in the if statement.